Guy and girl meeting for the first time alongside a bus stop
The movie starts with I think a guy and a girl meeting accidently for the first time alongside a bus stop on the road or something. I think "bus" was involved. I also think the guy went behind the girl towards her home I guess, with her permission it seems in some part of the movie. 
I am just not able to remember anything else. I think the movie revolved around this meeting and that it might have been a romantic one. I only remember that I saw that movie for like half an hour on TV and I had to leave for something urgent and I really loved it and thought that I would definitely catch up on it later but I forgot absolutely everything about it. 
Edit: The movie seemed to have been made between 1995-2005. Actors were young, in their 30s I would say. And their meeting (in a certain home) after the incident on the street might have been an accident which would mean that they met at two places accidentally. 

You are really going to have to come up with more than this ... any notable actors? When did you see it? Recent movie or something from the past (did it look like a '70s movie)? What you have here is just about nothing to work with.

@Paulster2 I have tried to add some more information. Hope that helps.

Very good addition ... should help a bit to get you a good answer.

What language movie? I can list a couple of Indian movies with the same scene.

The movie didn't star Matt Damon by any chance?

@Ramesh - It's definitely not Hindi movie.

@Tom - I don't think so.

"Actors were young, in their 30s" --> Thank you very much. I'd give you more than +1 if I could. O:-)

What did the actors look like?  What time period was the movie set in?  Where did the movie take place?

This is a long shot, and my memory is a bit sketchy, but the accidental meetings reminds me of Serendipity. John Cusack and Kate Beckinsale meet when they both try to buy the same pair of gloves. They have ice cream together. They leave the shop, she gets in a cab and he starts to head to the subway, then realizing he forgot his scarf, goes back into the store and runs into her again because she forgot her shopping bag, so they decide to go skating, despite both being engaged to other people. There is a scene where they are sitting on benches outside the ice rink, which is kind of like a bus stop in appearance. 
She gives him her phone number, but it blows away, so she thinks fate is against them. They test fate by going into a hotel and riding separate elevators to see if they both choose the same floor. They did choose the same floor, but his makes more stops and they miss each other. The rest of the movie they are both trying to find each other again.
Film came out in 2005.


That's not it unfortunately. I have seen Serendipity.

Maybe The Lake House (2006) or While You Were Sleeping (1995)
